# Proof of $(0,1)$ is not compact with usual metric.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

In the proof we say $\left\{\left(\frac1n,1\right):n\geq 1\right\}$ is an infinite cover with no finite subcover.

But, $(0,1)$ set also belongs to cover mentioned above. 
We can say $\{(0,1)\}$ is a subcover of mentioned above cover.

I am not able to understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: $(0,1)$ is not in the cover, as, there is no $n$ so that $1/n = 0$.

Comment: I don't get the downvote... Looks like people get downvoted when they misunderstand something. Isn't it one of the purpose here to get clarification and help on stuffs that are not understood well? Clearly OP seems to have think at the question (moreover OP took the time to format the question well with Mathjax etc.).

Comment: The space is metric and compactness in metric spaces is equivalent to complete and totally bounded. Consider the sequence ${1/n}$ is clearly Cauchy with the usual metric but does not converge to any point in $(0,1)$, then is not compact.

Answer (score 7):

$(0,1)$ is not in your open cover (for which integer $n$ is $0$ of the form $1/n$?). Therefore it can't be in a subcover.

To show that it has no finite subcover, take such a finite subcover. Being finite, it would have a maximum integer $n$ included, say $N$. But then the subcover is a subset of
$$ \left( \frac{1}{N}, 1 \right), $$
since every other $1/n$ is larger than $1/N$. Hence you miss any point between $0$ and $1/N$.

(Alternatively, use that a subset of a metric space is compact iff sequentially compact, and consider the sequence $1/n$, which is clearly Cauchy, &c.)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the open cover $C=\Big\{(\frac{1}{n},1):n\geq 2\Big\}$,. Since every $x\in (0,1)$  has $x>\frac{1}{n}$ for some $n$. But there is no finite subcover; if $x>0$, then $x\notin(\frac{1}{n},1)$ for all $n<\frac{1}{x}$. Thus no finite subcollection of $C$ can contain all $x\in  (0,1)$.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you go the following way:
First try to show all compact sets are closed, then see why (0,1) is not compact.

Comment: This is not a good approach to understand compactness ...